# Как преобразовать список со временем открытия и закрытия во временную шкалу?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, оптимизация, анализ-данных

Есть список заказов для двух филиалов A и B:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Office':['A','A','B','B','A','A','B'],
                'Start':['2019-12-01','2019-12-02','2019-12-02','2019-12-04','2019-12-05','2019-12-06','2019-12-06'],
                'End':['2019-12-03','2019-12-04','2019-12-07','2019-12-09','2019-12-08','2019-12-10','2019-12-10'],
                'Sum':[1.5,2,1,2.2,3.6,4,3.8]})

#   Office  Start   End         Sum
#0  A   2019-12-01  2019-12-03  1.5
#1  A   2019-12-02  2019-12-04  2.0
#2  B   2019-12-02  2019-12-07  1.0
#3  B   2019-12-04  2019-12-09  2.2
#4  A   2019-12-05  2019-12-08  3.6
#5  A   2019-12-06  2019-12-10  4.0
#6  B   2019-12-06  2019-12-10  3.8
```

Для каждого заказа есть время начала `Start` и время окончания `End`.
Нужно преобразовать во временную шкалу заказов в работе на каждый день.

```
#           A Sum_A B   Sum_B
#2019-12-01 1   0.0 0   0.0
#2019-12-02 2   0.0 1   0.0
#2019-12-03 2   1.5 1   0.0
#2019-12-04 1   2.0 2   0.0
#2019-12-05 1   0.0 2   0.0
#2019-12-06 2   0.0 3   0.0
#2019-12-07 2   0.0 3   1.0
#2019-12-08 2   3.6 2   0.0
#2019-12-09 1   0.0 2   2.2
#2019-12-10 1   4.0 1   3.8
```

`A` - количество открытых заказов:
`Sum_A` - сумма в день закрытия заказа:
`B` - количество открытых заказов:
Sum_B- сумма в день закрытия заказа:

Получил решение с помощью цикла вида:

```
for index, row in df1.loc[df1['Office']=='A'].iterrows()
```

Но на больших объемах расчет очень долгий.
Вот мое решение с циклами, совершенно не в стиле Pandas:

```
# создание DataFrame с результатами, первоначально заполняем 0.0
StartDate = df1['Start'].min()
EndDate = df1['End'].max()
idealTime = pd.date_range(StartDate, EndDate, freq='D')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0],
                    'Sum_A':[0.0],
                    'B':[0],
                    'Sum_B':[0.0]},
                    index = idealTime)

# цикл по строкам с Office='A'
for index, row in df1.loc[df1['Office']=='A'].iterrows():
    # Создание временного DataFrame
    StartDate_temp = row['Start']
    EndDate_temp = row['End']
    
    idealTime_temp = pd.date_range(StartDate_temp, EndDate_temp, freq='D')
    
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1],
                            'Sum_A':[0.0]},
                            index = idealTime_temp )
    
    # Для последней даты заказа запоняем сумму заказа   
    df_temp.iat[-1, 1] = row['Sum']
   
    # Прибавляем временный DF к DF c результатами
    df2 = df2.add(df_temp, fill_value = 0)
    
# цикл по строкам с Office='B'
for index, row in df1.loc[df1['Office']=='B'].iterrows():
    StartDate_temp = row['Start']
    EndDate_temp = row['End']
    
    idealTime_temp = pd.date_range(StartDate_temp, EndDate_temp, freq='D')
    
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'B':[1],
                            'Sum_B':[0.0]},
                            index = idealTime_temp )
    
    df_temp.iat[-1, 1] = row['Sum']

    df2 = df2.add(df_temp, fill_value = 0)
```

Есть ли более быстрое решение, например с использованием `apply()`, или векторное?

Comment: Лично мне непонятна логика расчета. Советую прокомментировать как высчитываются значения в столбцах `['A', 'B', 'Sum_A', 'Sum_B']` для первых четырех строк результата.

Comment: Вы всё же объясните как-то, что именно вы делаете. А то тут надо двойную работу проделать - сначала попытаться понять ваш алгоритм из вашего кода, а потом уже попытаться реализовать этот алгоритм более быстро.

Comment: Как минимум, наверняка можно всё сильно убыстрить, если есть возможность не использовать вообще Pandas во время расчётов и генерировать DataFrame-ы только на конечном этапе, после всех расчётов (если они вообще нужны).

Comment: df1 - время жизни заказа и сумма заказа. Результат нужно привести в единую временную шкалу. В колонке A - количество действующих заказов в данный день для офиса "A". В колонке Sum_A сумма от закрытого заказа. Она заполняется только в день закрытия заказа. Изначально в колонке Sum_A = 0.0.  2019-12-01 был только 1 заказ #0, 2019-12-02 - 2 заказа #0 и #1. 2019-12-03 - 2 заказа #0 и  #1. При этом заказ #0 закрылся и в колонку Sum_A прибавилась сумма от заказа #0 - 1.5. 2019-12-04 - 1 заказ #1, который в этот день закрывается и сумма от него 2.0 прибавляется к колонке Sum_A. Для "B" все так же.

Comment: По сути у меня получилось только сначала сделать результирующий DataFrame с индексом - дата с шагом 1 день. Начало открытие первого заказа и окончание последнего заказа. Затем в цикле пройти по всем заказам и каждый заказ превращать в DataFrame с индексом даты от начала до окончания и добавлять его к результирующему DataFrame

Comment: @Юрий, сколько у вас строк в вашем реальном фрейме с данными и какой максимальный разброс дат (т.е. сколько строк получается в результирующем фрейме )?

Comment: 500+ заказов в каждом офисе и 1 год общего результата.В реальности еще и суммирование задействованных ресурсов суммировать приходиться. В #0 заказе 2 человека, в #1 заказе - 3 человека. Привыполнении одновременно - 2+3=5 человек.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def fun(df):
    df["Date"] = df.apply(
        lambda row: pd.date_range(row["Start"], row["End"]).values,
        axis=1)
    t = df.drop(columns=["Start", "End"]).explode("Date").reset_index()
    idx = t.groupby(["index", "Office"]).apply(lambda x: x.index[-1])
    t["x"] = 0
    t.loc[idx, "x"] = df["Sum"].to_numpy()
    res = (t
           .groupby(["Date", "Office"])
           .agg(count=("Office", "count"), Sum=("x", "max"))
           .unstack(fill_value=0))
    res.columns = ["A", "B", "Sum_A", "Sum_B"]
    return res


res = fun(df1)
```

результат:

```
In [386]: fun(df1)
Out[386]:
            A  B  Sum_A  Sum_B
Date
2019-12-01  1  0    0.0    0.0
2019-12-02  2  1    0.0    0.0
2019-12-03  2  1    1.5    0.0
2019-12-04  1  2    2.0    0.0
2019-12-05  1  2    0.0    0.0
2019-12-06  2  3    0.0    0.0
2019-12-07  2  3    0.0    1.0
2019-12-08  2  2    3.6    0.0
2019-12-09  1  2    0.0    2.2
2019-12-10  1  1    4.0    3.8
```

---

### замеры времени для фрейма, сосотоящего из 7.000 строк

весь ваш код я оформил как функцию `fun2()` для удобства сравнения времени выполнения

```
big = pd.concat([df1] * 10**3, ignore_index=True)

In [393]: %timeit fun(big)
1.71 s ± 9.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [394]: %timeit fun2(big)
27.8 s ± 113 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [395]: big.shape
Out[395]: (7000, 5)
```

### разница по времени выполнения на моем железе - 16 раз:

```
In [396]: 27.8 / 1.71
Out[396]: 16.257309941520468
```

PS подозреваю, что можно еще ускорить код, воспользовавшись [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html), но мне лень ;)