# Группировка временного ряда с определение Начала и Окончания по группам

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть временной ряд:

```
import pandas as pd

myIndex = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-13')
myData ={'A':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(myData, index = myIndex)

            A
2019-01-01  1
2019-01-02  1
2019-01-03  1
2019-01-04  2
2019-01-05  2
2019-01-06  3
2019-01-07  3
2019-01-08  3
2019-01-09  3
2019-01-10  3
2019-01-11  4
2019-01-12  4
2019-01-13  4
```

Нужно сгруппировать по столбцу 'A' определить дату начала и дату окончания каждой группы.
Вот желательный результат:

```
    A   Start       End
0   1   2019-01-01  2019-01-03
1   2   2019-01-04  2019-01-05
2   3   2019-01-06  2019-01-10
3   4   2019-01-11  2019-01-13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная [с Pandas 0.25.0 в функции агрегирования можно задавать имена результирующим столбцам](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html).

Исходный DF:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
            A
2019-01-01  1
2019-01-02  1
2019-01-03  1
2019-01-04  2
2019-01-05  2
2019-01-06  3
2019-01-07  3
2019-01-08  3
2019-01-09  3
2019-01-10  3
2019-01-11  4
2019-01-12  4
2019-01-13  4
```

решение:

```
res = (df.reset_index()
         .groupby("A")
         .agg(Start=("index", "min"), End=("index", "max"))
         .reset_index())
```

результат:

```
In [8]: res
Out[8]:
   A      Start        End
0  1 2019-01-01 2019-01-03
1  2 2019-01-04 2019-01-05
2  3 2019-01-06 2019-01-10
3  4 2019-01-11 2019-01-13
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Уважаемые эксперты Pandas, не могли бы Вы помочь в решении обратного преобразования. Это вопрос чуть ниже https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074764/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так:

```
import pandas as pd
myIndex = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-13')
myData ={'A':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4],'B':myIndex}
df = pd.DataFrame(myData)
df.groupby(['A']).aggregate(["min","max"])
```

Результат:

```
    B
    min     max
A       
1   2019-01-01  2019-01-03
2   2019-01-04  2019-01-05
3   2019-01-06  2019-01-10
4   2019-01-11  2019-01-13
```